# R with Jupyter Notebook: Inner join two data frames on Date using dplyr

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, inner-join, jupyter-notebook

I am using R with Jupyter Notebook. I created two data frames using dplyr from the two files here: [CSV files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p1Ji5LUQ-1m-QgJjUPtGX0CjaRdKErEV)
To prep the data, I dropped columns form the "bikes" file and formatted the date string to a date-time.

```
# drop colums that contain only one value
bikes <- select(bikes,-c(contract_name, bonus,banking))
# convert UNIX timestamp to a date-time
bikes$last_update <- bikes$last_update/1000
bikes$last_update <- as.POSIXct(bikes$last_update, origin="1970-01-01")
```

I used the lubridate library to convert the "Santander_Weather_F" read in as "weath" to convert the date as well.

```
weath$Date <- parse_date_time(weath$Date, "mdy")
```

Here is how I created my new data frames:

```
avg_bikes_d <- bikes %>% select(last_update,available_bikes) %>% group_by(Date=lubridate::round_date(last_update,unit="day")) %>%
    summarise(avg_bikes=round(mean(available_bikes),0))
avg_weath <- weath %>% select(Date, temp_avg, wind_avg)
```

The number column of the first data frame contains values 1 through 14. Meaning that dates can be repeated. The head of the resulting data frames look like this:

```
| number | Date       | avg_bikes |
|--------|------------|-----------|
| 1      | 2017-05-30 | 0         |
| 1      | 2017-05-31 | 0         |
| 1      | 2017-06-01 | 2         |
| 1      | 2017-06-06 | 8         |
| 1      | 2017-06-07 | 17        |
| 1      | 2017-06-08 | 31        |

| Date       | temp_avg | wind_avg |
|------------|----------|----------|
| 2017-05-29 | 65       | 3        |
| 2017-05-30 | 64       | 3        |
| 2017-05-31 | 63       | 5        |
| 2017-06-01 | 66       | 3        |
| 2017-06-02 | 62       | 6        |
| 2017-06-03 | 61       | 5        |
```

I wish to do an inner join by Date:
 `avg <- inner_join(avg_bikes_d, avg_weath, by="Date")`
But all that results is an empty data frame.
I tried removing the number column of the first data frame as a check and still nothing. I checked that the Date columns were both formatted correctly using `is.POSIXct()` I also searched the dplyr documentation and other posts. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, it seems you are doing fine... Can you share the minimal data to reproduce this issue by `dput()` ?

Comment: I edited the question to include the data and my data cleaning process. I suspect my problem lies in how I reformatted the dates or how the dates are being read.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the detail about data.

This is because the timezones are different.

```r
avg_weath$Date[2]
#> [1] "2017-05-30 UTC"

# "JST" is my default timezone, so you probably get a different result.
avg_bikes_d$Date[1]
#> [1] "2017-05-30 JST"
```

c.f. https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3059

The first one a result of parsing digits **without timestamps**, so they are ambiguous. You know these two timestamps represents different points of time:

- `2017-05-30 00:00:00 UTC`
- `2017-05-30 00:00:00 JST`

But, by all rights, we cannot determine which one the digits `053017` represents actually. Here, `parse_date_time()` assumes the timezone is `UTC` (if `tz` argument is not supplied).

The second one comes from epoch seconds. This is irrelevant to timezone so we can determine the timestamp uniquely.

```r
bikes$last_update <- as.POSIXct(bikes$last_update, origin="1970-01-01")
```

Working with timezones is a tough job. One solution can be with `force_tz()`.

```r
avg_bikes_d$Date <- force_tz(avg_bikes_d$Date, "UTC")
```

But I guess what you actually need is dates, not timestamps. So, how about converting `Date` column to `Date` class instead of `POSIXct`?

```r
weath$Date <- date(parse_date_time(weath$Date, "mdy"))

avg_bikes_d <- bikes %>%
  select(last_update,available_bikes) %>%
  group_by(Date=date(last_update)) %>%
  summarise(avg_bikes=round(mean(available_bikes),0))
```

Comment: @lisa-de-castro I've updated my answer. Does this make sense?